Can I run large applications and Windows emulators from an external SSD on a 512GB M3 Pro MacBook Pro?
I'm planning to purchase a 14-inch MacBook Pro with an M3 Pro chip, 18GB of memory, and a 512GB SSD. My current Windows laptop has a 1TB SSD that's nearly full, mostly due to large applications rather than photos or videos.
Some of the applications I use regularly are MATLAB, AutoCAD, SolidWorks, and IDEs like Xcode and Visual Studio, all of which require significant storage space. Additionally, I plan to run a Windows emulator on the MacBook Pro to use applications like ANSYS, Siemens NX, COMSOL Multiphysics, and CATIA, which also demand lots of storage.
I'm considering installing and running these large applications, and possibly the emulators, directly from an external SSD to avoid the cost of upgrading the internal storage. While I'm willing to manage some performance degradation, I need to know if it's even possible to run these applications from an external drive. If anyone has experience with this setup, how noticeable was the performance hit?
Any thoughts on these issues would be greatly appreciated!

I've removed one of the multiple questions you had in there, feel free to search the site first to see if it was asked before and just ask it as a new question if not.

Also, this got posted on Reddit as well, the comments there might be interesting.

It seems to me the more logical approach would be to purchase a Windows Laptop. You have a significant amount of apps that seem to be only available on Windows - why get a Mac? The advantages that the Mac may have in some scenarios will IMO be insignificant to the disadvantages you run into when trying to run these large, intensive applications.

There is no general answer for this, basically "it depends":

Applications from the Mac App Store always install to /Applications on the main disk.
Applications from outside the Store which come with an installer usually install to /Applications as well.
Applications which are distributed in a DMG file (basically like a digital USB stick) are installed via drag&drop and can be installed anywhere.
VMs (e.g. for Windows) can be stored and started anywhere.

Now, you may be able to move non-store applications from /Applications to /Volumes/ExternalDisk/Applications but these usually come with libraries, support files etc. which take up a lot of space and remain on the main disk. There might be ways to change the installer to install everything to an external drive, but this needs to be looked at for each application seperatly. It may also break automated updates.
PS: Having said that: Even if Apple's price for additional disk space is high, I would recommend with 1 TB at least. Your needs will only grow over time.

Many applications want to be installed in the "Applications" folder, but that is mostly the applications themselves. Mine is not even one GB.
Some applications - very few, fortunately - insist on storing data on your internal drive. Two major culprits are "Books" and "Photos". "Music" and "Videos" can be on an external hard drive fortunately.
I myself use a Micron 2TB SSD drive. Quiet cheap, 44 grams, so you can glue it to your MacBook if you like. Reasonable fast. Well, nowhere near your internal SSD, but for a fifth of the price. A lot faster than a hard drive, and a lot smaller and lighter, and not much more expensive, and writing 250 GB in one go is quite fast. So is writing 100 GB every hour.
